# Adobe Illustrator 1-point perspective grid distorts the object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, grids, perspective

I plan to create a city scene in one point perspective, but I don't understand how does this tool work. The purple building is supposed to be tall and narrow, not long and short. When I double click the image on the grid to make it narrower and taller, it breaks the perspective. How can I fix it?

[image: Perspective grid makes the image long and short]